# php contact form subject encoding

Tags: php, forms

I have a contact form and I would like to add the name of the sender when I receive a message from the form.

The variable name is filtered like this:

```
$newname = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
```

then

```
mail($to, 'from: ' . $name, $body, $headers);
```

but my subject show &amp, &lt... instead of & or apostrophes
I did try this from other questions:

```
mail($to, 'from: ' . "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($name) . "?=", $body, $headers);
```

but no luck ...

If I remove the `htmlspecialchars()` of course it works, but I would like to keep it for protection

**EDIT**

This is not a duplicate.
Thanks, it's good to know that subject doesn't need to be escaped, but this is not a duplicate because I would like to know how can escape it and still correctly display in the subject (with no `&#039;` or `&amp`;). The

```
=?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=
```

solution proposed in that answer, makes things even worst in my case, with more weird characters... So, my question still is, why

```
"=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($name) . "?=",
```

is not working in my case?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11069897/2123530

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do email subjects need to be html escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002510/do-email-subjects-need-to-be-html-escaped)

Comment: Thanks Dev, good to know, but my question is: why "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($name) . "?=" doesn't work in my case? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What you are doing wrong is a useless `htmlspecialchars`. That is the one escaping your quotes, just don't do it because it is not needed.